# Help needed to determine inductor material/turns needed

Tags: analog, current-measurement, current-transformer

I am trying to formulate a circuit to sense current in a standard US 120V AC power line.  I'm planning on using an inductor as a current transformer to sense current flow and allow a microcontroller to be triggered.  However, to minimize size of the transformer, I'm planning on a BJT after the CT, in the hopes that I can amplify the signal enough to avoid bulky ferrous core material found in a typical CT.  (Proposed circuit below).  In analog TVs and older radios, I recall seeing coils wound with very dense, very small wire, and it made me wonder if I could trade core material for wire.

What might make this possible is that in my application, all I am trying to do is sense current above a very small and flexbile threshold (500 mA +/- 300 mA), not to measure it, so I don't need super duper accuracy, just ability to detect current flow above that amount.  I'm planning on wrapping that inductor around one lead of a standard 16 gauge copper Romex power feed cable.

Can anyone recommend any software or good reference sites with calculations that I can use to try to predict/simulate the kinds of voltages I can expect for a given wire diameter and number of turns in that inductor?

By the way, if anyone has a better design for the circuit in general, I'd love to find other potential ways to do this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This would be a better question if you found a current sense transformer, then we could help with the rest of the circuit.

Comment: `I'm planning on wrapping that inductor around one lead of a standard 16 gauge copper Romex power feed cable.` Do you mean making a long flexible inductor, and wrapping that round one lead of the romex, or winding wire round one lead of the romex? The former will get you a [Rogowski coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogowski_coil) which will work just fine, the second will do absolutely nothing. It would make sense to amplify first, then rectify, rather than rectify first as you've shown.

Comment: Thanks for those tips.  It was my understanding that the second option was essentially how a regular current transformer works.  (A regular coil around a wire).  That's good to know.  Thanks for the tip about rectifying later (to minimize losses before amplification, I'm assuming).

Comment: If you can use stuff from the scrapheap make your own current sensing transformer from an old mains AC step down transformer.  Insert a well insulated 1 turn winding for your sensed current and use the original mains AC primary as the output. Know there must be always a load to prevent an occasional high current to burn the original primary. Find with a stable about 200 mA AC test current  the proper resistor to the original primary. Start with 1kOhm.  If your current can vary widely (treshold = 200mA, maximum > 1A) consider to insert a clipping diode pair in parallel with the 1 turn winding.

Comment: @user287001 Thanks for this trick!  I have a ton of them laying around.  I should have mentioned I'm also fairly space-constrained in the box this will be in, so smaller is better, but if I can find one small enough, this would be an interesting and cool way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not wrap wire round the wire to be sensed. It doesn't work. You can't sense the magnetic field round the wire like that.

What you do in making a current transformer is to wrap a **magnetic circuit** round the wire, to sense the wire's magnetic field, then wrap a coil round the magnetic core, to sense the field in the core.

In a Rogowski coil, the magnetic core happens to be air, with a shape defined by the sense coils, which raises some problems, solved by making the coil very uniform, and by sensing the voltage and integrating.

In the case of a conventional current transformer, we either thread the wire through an existing toroid, or have a split core that we assemble round the wire.

A good tip for a DIY current transformer is to find a toroidal mains transformer, where the hole through the middle has been left open. Some transformers fill this hole with a glued-in mounting nut. Thread one, or a few, turns of the wire to be sensed through the hole, and use the original mains winding as your output.

**CAUTION** for large enough currents, you can generate mains-like voltages on your output. It's a good idea always to keep the output shorted, or loaded with a small resistor, or protected with some back-to-back zener diodes.

Answer (score 0):

Current sensing modules are easily available. You can search "ACS712 module" on any hobby electronics store. These modules have all necessary electronics implemented on board and just an input current port and an output voltage proportional to current. These are ready to be connected to a microcontroller or an Arduino.

An example is [from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13679).

Comment: Thanks for that input.  Yes, I did see those, but wanted to stick with more discrete parts for a couple reasons.  1) A challenge in analog design, and 2) cost reduction.  On the latter, the current sense modules are all around $8 from what I found, but I think the discrete parts cost could be half that.  Correct me if you know of cheaper current modules.

Comment: 2) Sparkfun is grossly overpriced. I searched "ACS712 modele" on Aliexpress. There are dozens of vendors selling this and all of them are below $ 1.2 for the 5A version :-)

Comment: 1) Please have my love for wanting a challenge in analog design. I would say go for a proper current current transformer, or CT as it's commonly known. Wrapping a wire around a current carrying conductor will be sloppy and unpredictable. Common CTs come with a current ratio of 500 -5,000 and I am pretty sure you wouldn't enjoy wrapping your wire around the conductor that many times. Then connect a resistor in parallel with the secondary winding of the CT (that's necessary). And then you can either {rectify it and use a filter capacitor if you just want to detect the presence of current}

Comment: ...or you can {use an analog amplifier to buffer the voltage signal and then measure it using an ADC, if you want to measure the value of the current}